# Is there a solar sail design that can deploy and retract at will?

Tags: solar-sail

I know [a mission to Venus was conducted using a solar sail](https://www.space.com/25800-ikaros-solar-sail.html) -- however, once unfurled using rotation kinetic energy, it could not be retracted. Would retracting a solar sail cause uncontrollable spinning? Or is there a known design that prevents things like this from occurring? How big of a sail is the design intended for, before it's not feasible?